# locate values in report filter in excel 2007 connecting a SSAS 2005 database

Tags: excel-2007, ssas

I created a pivot table in excel 2007 from a SSAS (2005) database. I have a product dimension, which has too many items. When I put it in report filter, I can either select all or go through all the items in it until I find the one I want. Is there a better way to do it? E.g. I enter xxx, then find all the items begins with the xxx.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I figure it out it can be done by not put the product in report filer, instead put it in rows (or columns). Then right click on it and choose filter - label filter, where I can enter the product name.